# Lazy evaluating string literals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-literals

I have a case where a template literal can resolve a variable immediately, but the next in order doesn't. I have to wait for a response. It looks like this:

```
const firstValue = 'firstItemName'
const myTemplate = `
    First item: ${firstValue} is available! But not the second: ${secondValue}
`;
const secondValue = 'secondItemName';
```

This `secondValue` will come, in my case, from a `Promise` call. Is there no way to use the string literal as a reference instead as final value?

Comment: can you precise the use case ? why do you want to do that ?

Comment: why don't you declare a function that return the string you want every time you want  passing firstValue and secondValue

Comment: @BasileBeldame Because I don't want to use React or any overkill library for a simple use case where I'm building a very, very small portion of my markup. The use case is...well, the general use-case of programming: build strings.

Comment: Just move the template string down after the code that awaited the promise. Or put it inside a function if you want to keep it at the top.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without wrapping it in a function. When this is evaluated, `myTemplate` is a string and strings are immutable. You need to create the string once you have the values or wrap the string creation in a function.